# Google map V.3 in a hidden div doesn't load all

Tags: google-maps

I know, this question has been asked many times and I tried all possible solutions, including:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setZoom( map.getZoom() );
```

, but none works for me.

So, I need to load page with a hidden map and to show map only when user clicks on link "Show map". The problem is that map doesn't display in full size. It appears in 181x186 px size but the rest is just a grey square.

```
This is my script: 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
ele.style.display = "none";
text.innerHTML = "Show map";
}
else {
ele.style.display = "block";
text.innerHTML = "Hide map";
}
} 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=handleApiReady"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleApiReady() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude;?>, <?php echo $longitude;?>);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 9,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude;?>, <?php echo $longitude;?>),
draggable: true,
icon: 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/factory.png', 
map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
document.getElementById("latitude").value = this.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById("longitude").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});
}
</script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="display:none;width:760px;height:420px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function toggle() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
  var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
  if(ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "Show map";
  }
  else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "Hide map";
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(myLatlng);
  }
} 
</script>
```

If I make myLatlng and map global.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_hiddenMap.html)

Comment: To summarize this up draw the map only when the div is visible not when it is hidden to avoid complications.

Comment: You can trigger the map "resize" event after the map's DOM is completely rendered.